# EntityFramework doesn't load the related object lazily

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am starting to use Entity Framework.

I have code modified from [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/data/jj193542)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace CodeFirstNewDatabaseSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new BloggingContext()) 
            {
                foreach (var post in db.Posts)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(post.Blog.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
    }

    public class BloggingContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and it works fine. But I have another code written by myself:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EFTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var ctx = new DataBaseContext())
            {
                foreach (var account in ctx.Accounts)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(account.User.Name); // NullRef here
                }
            }
        }
    }



    class User
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

    }

    class Account
    {
        public int AccountId { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }

    class DataBaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The result of me code is `NullReferenceException`.

Using MS SQL Server Management Studio, I see the content of tables:

`Accounts`:

```
+-----------+--------+
| AccountId | UserID |
+-----------+--------+
|         1 |      2 |
|         2 |      2 |
+-----------+--------+
```

`Users`:

```
+--------+-------+
| UserID | Name  |
+--------+-------+
|      1 | Vasya |
|      2 | Petya |
|      3 | Masha |
+--------+-------+
```

When I add `ctx.Entry(account).Reference(p => p.User).Load();` before `Console.WriteLine` it starts working fine, but I want to use lazy loading

Both databases was generated automatically from the source (It's called Code First I believe).

What is the difference? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In MS SQL, do both tables have primary key defined?

Comment: @BishnuPaudel, yes, Also Accounts table has `FK`:  `FK_dbo.Accounts_dbo.Users_UserId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your classes' scope to public and it should work .

Comment: That's the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to eager load the related entities.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx for an excellent article on how to do this.

Comment: and why I can't use lazy loading? According this article it's enabled by default for virtual's